# R - Tricky CSV Printout

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, subset

I have a tricky printout format I'm trying to get.  Here is my dataframe currently, which is built by a for loop and rbind.

```
bets<- data.frame(status=character(), f_name=character(), d_name=character(), type_bet=character(), sec=character(),
                  spread=character(), total=character(), deriv=character(), book=character(), edge=character(), 
                  my_f_price=character(), book_f_price=character(), my_d_price=character(), book_d_price=character())
```

Sample printout:

```
status  f_name  d_name  type_bet    sec spread  total   deriv   book    edge    my_f_price  book_f_price    my_d_price  book_d_price

9:00 PM ET  San Diego State Colorado State  total   h1  3.5 138.5   65  pin 12  120 -108    -120    -108
9:00 PM ET  San Diego State Colorado State  total   h1  3.5 138.5   65  5d  10  120 -110    -120    -110
6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU total   h1  8   125.5   59  pin 9   122 -103    -122    -113
8:00 PM ET  Temple  Rutgers total   h1  1.5 150 70.5    pin 8   116 -108    -116    -108
8:00 PM ET  Temple  Rutgers total   h1  1.5 150 70.5    5d  6   116 -110    -116    -110
8:05 PM ET  Drake   Evansville  ml  h1  7   136 0   5d  4   -214    -210    214 175
8:00 PM ET  Northern Iowa   Bradley total   h1  12  133 62  5d  3   113 -110    -113    -110
6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU ml  h1  8   125.5   0   5d  2   -242    -240    242 200
6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU total   h1  8   125.5   58.5    5d  2   112 -110    -112    -110
```

It's a little hard to see, but the edge column is how it's ordered, 12, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2.  What I want to do is group some entries together though.  When the f_name, d_name, type_bet, and sec are all the same, and the only column that is different is the book, that should be considered one group.  So ideally, I'd like the printout to look like this:

```
status  f_name  d_name  type_bet    sec spread  total   deriv   book    edge    my_f_price  book_f_price    my_d_price  book_d_price

9:00 PM ET  San Diego State Colorado State  total   h1  3.5 138.5   65  pin 12  120 -108    -120    -108
9:00 PM ET  San Diego State Colorado State  total   h1  3.5 138.5   65  5d  10  120 -110    -120    -110

6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU total   h1  8   125.5   59  pin 9   122 -103    -122    -113
6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU total   h1  8   125.5   58.5    5d  2   112 -110    -112    -110

8:00 PM ET  Temple  Rutgers total   h1  1.5 150 70.5    pin 8   116 -108    -116    -108
8:00 PM ET  Temple  Rutgers total   h1  1.5 150 70.5    5d  6   116 -110    -116    -110

8:05 PM ET  Drake   Evansville  ml  h1  7   136 0   5d  4   -214    -210    214 175

8:00 PM ET  Northern Iowa   Bradley total   h1  12  133 62  5d  3   113 -110    -113    -110

6:00 PM ET  Cincinnati  SMU ml  h1  8   125.5   0   5d  2   -242    -240    242 200
```

Right now the only way I can think to print to a txt file line by line, looping through the dataframe (ordered by the edge column), and for each entry I can search through the rest of the dataframe for another entry with the same f_name, d_name, type_bet, sec and print that too, and delete it from the dataframe.  But I think there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using my own data frame because it was less work than processing the text string above.

Assume the variables you wanted to form a group were called `formGroupVarX` (in your case "f_name", "d_name", "type_bet", "sec") and the variable outside of that `FreeVarX` (all other vars) then you could display it as following:

```
formGroupVars = c("formGroupVar1","formGroupVar2","formGroupVar3")
freeVars = c("FreeVar1")
frameToShow <- data.frame(cbind(sample(LETTERS[1:3],20,replace=TRUE),sample(LETTERS[4:6],20,replace=TRUE),
                                sample(LETTERS[7:9],20,replace=TRUE),sample(letters,20,replace=TRUE)        ))
colnames(frameToShow) = c(formGroupVars,freeVars)
frameToShow[order(apply(frameToShow,1,function(X) {  paste(X[formGroupVars],collapse="")   } )),]
```

Basically you create a temporary factor level that consists of a function of the all the variables you want to form a group and order your display on that temporary factor. In your and my example a simple concatenation of values does the trick but in theory this function could be a mathematical function or any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data (you can use dput(yourData) to produce this - makes it alot easier to help)

```
df <- structure(list(status = c("9:00 PM ET", "9:00 PM ET", "6:00 PM ET", 
 "8:00 PM ET", "8:00 PM ET", "8:05 PM ET", "8:00 PM ET", "6:00 PM ET", 
"6:00 PM ET"), f_name = c("San Diego State", "San Diego State", 
"Cincinnati", "Temple", "Temple", "Drake", "Northern Iowa", "Cincinnati", 
"Cincinnati"), 
 d_name = c("Colorado State", "Colorado State", "SMU", "Rutgers", "Rutgers", 
  "Evansville", "Bradley", "SMU", "SMU"), type_bet = c("total", "total", "total",      
"total", "total", 
 "ml", "total", "ml", "total"), sec = c("h1", "h1", "h1", "h1", 
 "h1", "h1", "h1", "h1", "h1"), spread = c(3.5, 3.5, 8, 1.5, 1.5, 
7, 12, 8, 8), total = c(138.5, 138.5, 125.5, 150, 150, 136, 133, 
125.5, 125.5), deriv = c(65, 65, 59, 70.5, 70.5, 0, 62, 0, 58.5), 
 book = c("pin", "5d", "pin", "pin", "5d", "5d", "5d", "5d", 
 "5d"), edge = c(12L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L), my_f_price = c(120L, 
 120L, 122L, 116L, 116L, -214L, 113L, -242L, 112L), book_f_price = c(-108L, 
-110L, -103L, -108L, -110L, -210L, -110L, -240L, -110L), my_d_price = c(-120L, 
-120L, -122L, -116L, -116L, 214L, -113L, 242L, -112L), book_d_price = c(-108L, 
 -110L, -113L, -108L, -110L, 175L, -110L, 200L, -110L)), .Names = c("status", 
"f_name", "d_name", "type_bet", "sec", "spread", "total", "deriv", 
"book", "edge", "my_f_price", "book_f_price", "my_d_price", "book_d_price" ),
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

#You can sort your data on the required columns - but doesn't produce exactly the output you want
df2 <- df[order(df$f_name, df$d_name, df$type_bet, df$sec) , ]
```

Unsure what the structure of output that you want 
(ie what are the blank lines between the groups?), but you can get close to this using lists.

```
#Split data by required groups (and remove empty dataframes produced by interaction)
df.grp <- split(df , list(df$f_name, df$d_name, df$type_bet, df$sec))
df.grp <- df.grp[sapply(df.grp, function(z) nrow(z)>0)]

#Get in the order of decreasing edge
max.edge <- unlist(lapply(df.grp , function(x) max(x[,'edge'])))
list.names <- names(sort(max.edge, decreasing=T))
(out <- df.grp[match(names(df.grp),list.names)])
```

Comment: sorry ill try to make the printout, reproducbileness better in future